# If $(A \vee B) \wedge (¬B \vee C)$ is true, then $(A \vee C)$ must be true ... can I argue that?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> If $(A \vee B) \wedge (¬B \vee C)$ is true, then $(A \vee C)$ must be true ... can I argue that?

I don't see how I can argue that $(A \vee C)$ must be true because can't we have 
$(T \vee T) \wedge (F \vee F) \Rightarrow T \wedge T \Rightarrow T$ and it still is true even though both sides of the "or" are true? So how can I argue that $(A \vee C)$ must be true?

Comment: Thanks for the edits.. .first time here and I love how some of my stuff copied over correctly and some didn't.. oh well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try proof by contraposition. It simplifies things up in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I feel I got that one pretty easily.. actually typing it out makes it take a lot longe.. at least for me, haha. I need to get better at that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(A\lor B) \land (\lnot B \lor C)$$

If the premise above is true, then by conjunction elimination,

- $A\lor B$ is true $(1)$
- and $\lnot B \lor C \equiv B\rightarrow C$ is true.$(2)

$(1) \;A:\;$Suppose A is true. Then $A\lor C$ is true ($\lor$-Introduction).

$(1)\;B:\;$ Suppose B is true. Then by modus ponens with $(2): B\rightarrow C$, we have that $C$ is true. If C is true, then so is $A\lor C$, by $\lor$-Introduction.

In either case, $A\lor B$, which being true means $A$ is true or $B$ is true (or both) we have shown that with $(2)$, it follows that $A\lor C$ must be true.

Comment: You know what? I feel like a GIANT moron. I misread what the teacher wrote on the paper. I completely mixed up the Or and AND symbols... well then.. I think my logic was sound outside of the symbols being comletely misunderstood.. wow.. thanks though!!

Comment: You're welcome, Chris. You're *not* a moron!

Comment: Hahaha, well I am not a moron, but I do make light of myself. I can't take myself too seriously.

Answer (score 2):

You always have  $B\lor \lnot B$.

If $B$ then $\lnot B\lor C$ implies $C$ which on its turn implies $A\lor C$.

If $\lnot B$ then $A\lor B$ implies $A$ which on its turn implies $A\lor C$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an equivalence, it's an implication.

We need to show: $(A\wedge B)\vee(\neg B\wedge C)\to (A\vee C)$

$\begin{align}
& (A\wedge B)\vee(\neg B\wedge C) & \text{Premise}
\\
\iff & ((A\wedge B)\vee\neg B)\wedge ((A\wedge B)\vee C) & \text{Distribution}
\\
\iff & ((A\vee\neg B)\wedge (B\vee\neg B))\wedge ((A\wedge B)\vee C) & \text{Distribution}
\\
\iff & ((A\vee\neg B)\wedge \top)\wedge ((A\wedge B)\vee C) & \text{Complementation}
\\
\iff & (A\vee\neg B)\wedge((A\wedge B)\vee C) & \text{Identity}
\\
\iff & (A\vee\neg B)\wedge((A\vee C)\wedge (B\vee C)) & \text{Distribution}
\\
\iff & (A\vee C)\wedge((A\vee\neg B)\wedge(\wedge (B\vee C)) & \text{Commutivity}
\\[2ex]
\therefore & (A\wedge B)\vee(\neg B\wedge C)\implies (A\vee C)
\end{align}$

Comment: Something went wrong, because the original is compatible with $A = T, B = F, C = F$ but the conclusion is not.

Comment: @CarlMummert, indeed. I confused myself.  I tried to show that it was an equivalence; however it is merely an implication.